# AngularJS nested views & controllers

Tags: angularjs, routes, navigation

Below is my application layout:

[image]

**app.html** code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#admin">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sales">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#purchase">Purchase</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-include="view.url">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**/static/app/controllers.js** is:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {

        $scope.$watch(
            function () {
                return $location.path();
            },
            function (path) {
                var moduleName = path.split("/")[1];
                if (moduleName) {
                    $scope.view = { url: "/static/app/" + moduleName + "/" + moduleName + ".html" };
                }
            });

    } ]);
```

Now let say **admin.html** is:

```
<div>
    <p>Admin</p>
</div>
```

and sales.html, and purchase.html are just about the same. Then my app's navigation works just as expected; when admin link is clicked, admin.html is loaded and shown.
But if **admin.html** is as follows:

```
<div>
    <p>Admin</p>
    <script src="/static/app/admin/controllers.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="AdminCtrl" ng-include="subView.url">
    </div>
</div>
```

and **/app/admin/controllers.js** is

```
var admin = angular.module('MyApp.Admin', []);

admin.controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {


    } ]);
```

then when admin link is clicked, the following error is thrown in Google Chrome console:

```
Error: Argument 'AdminCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    at Error (<anonymous>)
```

If I move AdminCtrl to /app/controllers.js, then it works; but I would prefer it to be in its own directory. Can someone help me with this? Also, next step is to display "subView", similar way as "view" is navigated. Any hint on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect your `MyApp` module (in its definition) with your `MyApp.Admin` modulelikes this:

`angular.module('MyApp', ["MyApp.Admin"]);`

But for a larger app, you might want to look at the [UI-Router project](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead...

Comment: @synergetic make sure MyApp.Admin is declared before the MyApp module, you'll need to be sure your scripts are loaded in order.

Comment: As a matter of fact, don't load just one `controllers.js` file in your head, because it gets loaded before every other file, and doesn't recognize yet the other modules... I would put them together, or load the app controllers file at the end of the file.. by the way, I think calling your conrtollers.js file something like `admin.ctrl.js` is preferable, hope it helps

Comment: To add to the suggestions I have a folder for my html partials (called app/partials/), just helps to keep the HTML separated from the JS and keep everything organized.

Comment: So.. did it help with your issue?